# Postgis different result using st_length and st_intersection

Tags: postgis, polygon, line, length

I'm trying a simple intersection between line and polygon

```
SELECT p.id,
st_length(st_intersection (l.geometry,p.geometry)) as partial_length,
st_length(l.geometry) as line_length
FROM line l ,  polygon p
WHERE st_intersects (l.geometry,p.geometry)
```

the query returns:

```
id  partial_length  line_length
17020   10389   32248
17125   5047    32248
17159   3151    32248
17195   2568    32248
17196   3905    32248
17200   2009    32248
```

Sum of partials lengths are not equal to line_length.

Polygons are adjacent. I cannot post the geometry because I exceeded character limit

Here's an image of line and polygon with id:
[image]

[original image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qggywx37k7inh32/line_polygonid.png?dl=0)

Line maybe has some overlaps. It may be the cause?

```
l.geometry is
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
```

Comment: If the line is not totally inside your polygon the intersection is shorter than the original line. Or perhaps I do not understand what you are doing. Could you add a screenshot of your geometries, or one line and one polygon as WKT?

Comment: Please update your question to include what your final goal to achieve is.

Comment: Your query columns (l.id,p.id,partial_length,line_length) don't match the result columns (id,partial_length,line_length).  I only noticed because I was wondering if you would please turn on labels on your image to show the polygon IDs.

Comment: sorry. I edit query and image

Comment: Does ST_3DIntersection give a different result than st_intersection?

Comment: And if that doesn't work, then try ST_3DLength rather than st_length.

Comment: st_3dintersection(geometry, geometry) does not exist

Comment: st_3dintersection(geography, geography) does not exist

Comment: check your version... I have v2.2.2 rl4797.   `SELECT PostGIS_full_version();`

Comment: nevermind... ST_3DIntersection is going to make it worse now that I think about it.

Comment: postgis version is 2.2.1

Comment: what does this result in?  `SELECT p.id,
st_length(st_intersection (l.geometry,p.geometry)) as partial_length,
st_length(l.geometry) as line_length,ST_IsSimple(l.geometry)`

Comment: st_issimply  return f

Comment: and this?  `SELECT p.id,
st_length(st_intersection (ST_Simplify(l.geometry),p.geometry)) as partial_length,
st_length(ST_Simplify(l.geometry)) as line_length`

Comment: I try with `ST_Length (ST_Simplify(t.geometry::geography,0.1))::geography` SR is 4326 and I have casted all geometry to geography to work with lengths. Anyway it doesnt work length go from 32 km to 14 km

Comment: Try `ST_IsValidDetail(l.geometry)`.  If the lines are overlapping themselves, do you really want to count the overlapping sections as part of your length?  I suspect that ST_Intersection() is returning a simplified line, so you might try ST_3DIntersection which should be available as of 2.1.0.  But since that isn't available to you then perhaps your postgis installation contains some old code and isn't really at the correct version?

Comment: `ST_Isvaliddetail` return (t,,) . I doesnt know why `ST_3DInteresction` doen't work since I have 2.2.1 version of Postgis. Yes I'd count the overlapping line.

Comment: FYI, you likely do have ST_3DIntersection but it isn't working because you are passing in geography types but it only accepts geometry types.

Comment: Yes sure. I try with geometry also function st_3dintersection(geometry, geometry) does not exist

Comment: `SELECT p.proname AS funcname,  d.description
 FROM pg_proc p
   INNER JOIN pg_namespace n ON n.oid = p.pronamespace
   LEFT JOIN pg_description As d ON (d.objoid = p.oid )
     WHERE p.proname ILIKE '%st_3DI%'
   ORDER BY n.nspname, p.proname ;`

Comment: Updated answer for dissolving self-intersections for line_length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE**

The line has some self-intersections that are being dissolved by ST_Intersection.

You'll need to dissolve those on the line_length yourself with [ST_UnaryUnion](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi8iofLtLDQAhVPyGMKHeQMAU8QFggbMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fpostgis.net%2Fdocs%2FST_UnaryUnion.html&usg=AFQjCNEBV97tvfBTCq_ZWmpWm3WKyG_-hg&sig2=H5134LYHIw-bvIT1j6vDHA&bvm=bv.139250283,d.amc):

```
SELECT SUM(ST_Length(ST_Intersection(l.geometry,p.geometry))) as sum_partial_length,
    ST_Length(ST_UnaryUnion(l.geometry::geometry)::geography) as line_length
FROM l,p
WHERE ST_Intersects(l.geometry,p.geometry)
GROUP BY l.geometry
```

---

The sum of a partial line is always going to be less than or equal to the length of a line.

```
WITH l as (SELECT 1234 as id,ST_MakeLine(ST_MakePoint(2,0), ST_MakePoint(2,3)) as geometry),
p as (SELECT 2345 as id,ST_MakePolygon(ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(0 2,4 2,4 4,0 4,0 2)')) as geometry)
SELECT l.id,p.id,
    ST_Length(ST_Intersection (l.geometry,p.geometry)) as partial_length,
    ST_Length(l.geometry) as line_length
FROM l,p
WHERE ST_Intersects (l.geometry,p.geometry)
```

[image]

[image]

and with the line contained within the polygon:

```
WITH l as (SELECT 1234 as id,ST_MakeLine(ST_MakePoint(2,0), ST_MakePoint(2,3)) as geometry),
p as (SELECT 2345 as id,ST_MakePolygon(ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(0 -2,4 -2,4 4,0 4,0 -2)')) as geometry)
SELECT l.id,p.id,
    ST_Length(ST_Intersection (l.geometry,p.geometry)) as partial_length,
    ST_Length(l.geometry) as line_length,l.geometry,p.geometry
FROM l,p
WHERE ST_Intersects (l.geometry,p.geometry)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: If polygons contains all the line this is not true

Comment: @franco_b I updated the answer to include the results from when the line  is enclosed within the poly which proves my statement.

Comment: @franco_b  Perhaps I am misunderstanding but, the sum of a partial line (3 or 27) is always going to be less than or equal to the length of a line (3 or 32).

Comment: I have line completely enclosed in 6 polygon. Line length = 32 km. Sum of 6 partial line length after intersection beween line an polygon = 27 km. And I don't understand where is the error because I expect the same length.

Comment: @franco_b I updated the answer.